# html2canvas shifting text downwards

Tags: tailwind-css, html2canvas

I am trying to convert a `<div>` to an image using html2canvas. However, there's an issue. The text inside the `<div>` marked with the red circle in `Figure 1` has no padding or any kind of offset introducing parameters. But when converted to an image, there's an error gap above the text as shown by the red circle in `Figure 2`. I have used `<h3>` (marked with black background) and a `<span>` (marked with a green background).

`Figure 1`

[image: Figure 1]

`Figure 2`

[image: Figure 2]

Why is it behaving this way and is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: This is a pending issue that is still not resolved. Here's the link to relevant github issue https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2775

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tailwind CSS sets the `display` property of the `img` tag to `display: block;` during preflight. This introduces a line-break below the element which is not seen in the UI render. But, when you convert the same HTML to Image using `html2canvas`, the line-break gets rendered thus adding an unnecessary space in the resulting image. To solve this, we can add the following code to the `tailwind.css` file.

```
@layer base {
  img {
    @apply inline-block;
  }
}
```

The above piece of code should be added after the `@tailwind base;` line. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: How do we do this without affecting the whole project?

Comment: You can use Custom CSS through inline styling to handle this as shown below:

.random-class {
   display: inline-block !important;
}

try this an let me know.

Comment: Yes, it worked. just before the creation of the pdf, I added the style to the dom and then removed it after pdf creation. Thank you

Comment: I am using Chakra UI and I applied this in theme.js to all images and it worked! It's very helpful, thank you.